# Data command missing in sf CLI

Tags: cli, commandline, sf

I am not able see "data" in sf command CLI
Can you help  me why I am not able to see[image]

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_data_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_data_commands_unified) does have information about `data` commands. Are you really on version 1.44.0? If so, that is _extremely out of date_. The current version is **2.21**

Comment: It is version issue only...now it is showing data command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.44 is old, the current version a time of writing is 2.21 (a difference of a few *hundred* releases!)

So the fix here is simply one of the common IT troubleshooting steps, making sure you're on the most recent version.

`sf update` should do the trick.